# Difference between unexpected and unpredictable - with examples

Tags: differences

Can anyone please tell me, when we should use unexpected and unpredictable with short example. Thanks

Comment: I think your question lacks any research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitions:

- Expect: To consider likely to happen soon.
- [Unexpected](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unexpected?s=t): Considered unlikely to happen, not to occur soon.
- Predict: To be able to anticipate; foresee (from Latin: to say before it happens).
- [Unpredictable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unpredictable?s=t): Unforeseeable; cannot say ahead of time.

Examples:

- Tomorrow's weather is unpredictable. (Who knows what it will be.)
- My friend's arrival was unexpected. (I didn't think they would arrive; it was a surprise.)

Answer (score 1):

Something that is *unpredictable* is something that is not able be predicted and something that is unexpected is something that is not able to be expected.

*predict* [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/predict):

> Say or estimate that (a specified thing) will happen in the future or will be a consequence of something.

*expect* [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/expect?q=expected):

> Regard (something) as likely to happen.

If I *predict* something, I am making a claim that something will happen with an understanding of the situation.

If I *expect* something, I think something will happen, but I don't necessarily have any proof.

*Predict* is more of a *calculation* and *expect* is more of a *feeling*.

Examples:

> *Winning the lottery is unpredictable.*
>
> *Her joke was unexpected.*

Answer (score 1):

[Unpredictable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unpredictable) is used for events and behaviors that are difficult or impossible to predict or foresee.

An animal placed in a cage may be unpredictable.
Where a roulette ball lands on the wheel is unpredictable.
The time of one's demise is unpredictable

[Unexpected](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unexpected) is used for events and behaviors that occur without warning.

Sometimes we are interrupted by unexpected phone calls or visitors at the office.
Accidents are unexpected.
Traffic delays are often referred to as unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to something as "unexpected" you say that you couldn't even think it might have happened, like in that famous phrase "Shit happens" E.g. "She liked him none the worse for it, and even began to think how to deal with the situation, when for the second time the unexpected happened to her." Agatha Christie's Philomel Cottage. If you refer to something as "unpredicted" or "unpretictable" you say that you had some options in your head how it might happen but everything turned out otherwise. "Unpredicted"or "unpredictable" means out of predicted options. "Unexpected" means that no one even thought it might happen.  Interesting to note though that if a person is unpredictable they behave out of the pre-set norms, but if a person can do something no one can ever think of they are called "sudden"